# Firefox Session lost

Tags: firefox

The old version of Firefox I used, had installed session store plugin to recover and to save sessions of tabs, I installed updates and my Firefox is now Quantum so I lost my tabs, aprox 300. How can I recover my tabs? Should I install prior version of Firefox and how do I do that? I have a copy of the Firefox profile that I want to restore where are all my sessions saved, bookmarks history etc, Firefox Quantum isn't compatible with this `plugin:session` store.

Comment: You answered your question yourself, Firefox Quantum is not compatible with some old plugins, if you want to access your profile, then you have to use an old version of Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The following may help:

1. Create a copy of the Firefox profile you wish to revive (the following may kill it)
2. Download [Firefox ESR](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/) and extract its binaries somewhere (it currently, as of January 2018) still supports XPCOM/XUL/JetPack based extensions)
3. Open the extracted directory in a terminal and type `./firefox -P "${PATH_TO_THE_COPY_OF_THE_PROFILE}" -no-remote` (substituting the appropriate path) to launch Firefox ESR with the old profile

   - This will DOWNGRADE the profile and can, and **has been observed in some cases** to, **cause severe problems and loss of data**! (Use a copy… really!)
4. Open Firefox preferences and set *When Firefox is launched* to *Restore tabs and windows of last session*
5. Uninstall the tab management add-on (possibly following some add-on specific guide to tranfering the tabs to Firefox's internal session manager)
6. Close Firefox ESR
7. Open the ESR again using the command above

   - If the tabs appear again you're good, otherwise you're probably out of luck…
8. Close *all* instances of Firefox (ESR or not)
9. Go to the copy of the profile directory that you used to launch Firefox ESR and copy the *sessionstore.js* file to your new (post-Quantum) main profile (replacing the one that should already be there)
10. Launch your main Firefox instance again – hopefully your session should be back!
11. (Optional) Install a [new/compatible session management extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/search/?platform=linux&q=session&type=extension) – if you just need crash recovery you'll find that the Firefox internal session manager is extremely reliable at this point (at least for me it hasn't lost any tabs in years)

A few *if*s and *but*s, but hopefully this is useful regardless!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply ,it wasn't that difficult ,i now have all my bookmars and history restored on latest quantum firefox but still don't know how to acces my saved sessions ,since sessione store plugin is not available on quantum firefox, i have the files on the remote firefox profile that i manage to backup ,is there other plugin compatible to quantum firefox that can work ?!